# NSString to NSDate conversion and NSDate don't give only date

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ios6, nsdate, xcode4.5

Hope you will doing good.

I have a date (November 14, 2012) in label, it means that

`Label.text returns the string "November 14, 2012"`

Now what I want is to convert this string into `NSDate`. I did it by using this code snippet.

```
formator.dateStyle=NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
formator.dateFormat=@"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formator stringFromDate:myDatePicker.date]];
NSLog(@"%@",temp);
NSDate *myDate=[formator dateFromString:temp];
NSLog(@"%@",myDate);
```

`myDatePicker.date`output`= November 14,2012`

`temp's`output`= 2012-11-14`

`myDate's`output`= 2012-06-13 19:00:00 +0000`

`myDate` is also giving me time and GMT setting and also 1 day behind date i.e 13 instead of 14, which I really don't want to get. I just need only the date.

My requirement is to get the output of `myDate` **2012-11-14**

Thanks for all of your help in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and let me know :

```
NSDate *dateTemp = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
[dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

dateTemp = [dateFormat1 dateFromString:newInvoice.date];
newDate.date = [dateFormat2 stringFromDate:dateTemp];
```

This will be helpfull :

```
-(NSDate *)dateWithOutTime:(NSDate *)datDate
    if( datDate == nil ) {
        datDate = [NSDate date];
    }
    NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:datDate];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
}
```

Comment: if you find the answer, never hesitate to tick it :)

Comment: Anoop Vaidya :: Thanks for answering soon buddy. but I think we have just missed the track of the question. The end result I want is `NSDate` to be only `date` without `time` and `+GMT` settings.

In your answer `newDate` is type of `NSString`. I don't need NSString. I need NSDate.

Comment: Anoop Vaidya :: Sorry, unfortunately it is not working, it is still giving time stamp like `(2012-11-13 19:00:00 +0000)`. I tried it twice. I know we are not much far away from the result, but actually I am just stuck here :-(

Comment: @Azeem I am missing somethere... I guess you have to endup with String, or NSDate will always contain time with it :(

Comment: :: But actually I have to do this. Anyways, thanks for you time buddy. If I found anything, definitely will post as a answer on this question.

Comment: One more thing i want to add, if you truncate the timestamp, you will loose timezone. so better stuck with nsdate.

Comment: Look Up NSFormatter Docu, keywords: setTimeStyle setDateStyle